# Bash: printing var into text file and adding text at the end of the same line

Tags: bash, shell

I have this function, I'm trying to add "MM" at the end of the line in case the line doesn't contain "MM" and it print it at the start of the line all the time..

```
recursiveFindReq `pwd`/allReqTemp.txt
while read line; do
        if [[ $line != *MM* ]]; then
                echo $line MM >> temp2
        else
                echo $line >> temp2
        fi
done < allReqTemp.txt
```

here's the OUTPUT FOR CODE ABOVE [image: OUTPUT FOR CODE ABOVE]

and MM BEFORE $LINE [image: MM BEFORE $LINE]

and USING PRINTF [image: USING PRINTF]

for example:
  for the input :

> 07/2018 08:00 09/07/2018 08:01 09:00 150

I expect :

> 07/2018 08:00 09/07/2018 08:01 09:00 150 MM

but I get :

> " MM07/2018 08:00 09/07/2018 08:01 09:00 150"

as you can see in pics

***succeed!*** took me just 2 hours

```
while read -a line; do
        if [[ ${line[*]} != *MM* ]]; then
                line[6]=MM
                echo ${line[0]} ${line[1]} ${line[2]} ${line[3]} ${line[4]} ${line[5]} ${line[6]} >> temp2
        else
                echo ${line[*]} >> temp2
        fi
done < allReqTemp.txt
```

Comment: when you post images, instead of text it's not possible to copy/paste and use for testing the scripts.

Comment: Did you generate your input file on a Windows box? If so, it's possible that each line has a `^M` at the end, which would reset the cursor to the beginning of the line before your script prints `MM`.  Try checking the structure of the line endings with `od -c allReqTemp.txt` or `cat -v -e allReqTemp.txt` to make sure.

Comment: did you try to remove the end of line char for each $line before processing it?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want to do but perhaps this may provide some guidance.

for the input file

```
$ cat file
1
2
3MM
4MM
5
6
```

this will produce

```
$ awk '{print $0 (/MM$/?"":"MM")}' file

1MM
2MM
3MM
4MM
5MM
6MM
```

will print the current line (`$0`) and a suffix if the suffix is not already at the end of the line (`/MM$/`).  Note that this won't allow any white space after the suffix.

Comment: i'm just want to add the "MM" at the END of the line

Comment: what does that : "awk '{print "MM" $0 (/MM$/?"":"MM")}' file" do?

Comment: what did you mean with "print it at the start of the line all the time.." then?

Comment: that is my problam, i want to add it at the end of the line

Comment: Yes I understand it's your problem but you're asking the script to do this, no?  Please create a simple input file and expected output to eliminate any misunderstandings.

Comment: ok, be right back

Comment: input file and expected output added @karakfa

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the line for each line before processing it:

add this to your code: to remove end of line char:

## `${line/$'\n'}`

```
   while read line; do
       new_line=${line/$'\n'}
       if [[ $new_line != *MM* ]]; then
            echo $new_line MM >> temp2
       else
            echo $new_line  >> temp2
       fi
   done < file1`
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. Did you mean `$'\r'`?